# code a variable with the values of multiple variables

Tags: r, data-science

I need to code a new variable with the values found in 4 previous variables.
If col 1:4 have value 1 or 2, I want the new variable to assign to take that value either one or 2.

sample data.

```
df1<- (data.frame(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
              var1 = c(1,0 ,2 ,0 ,0 ),
              var2 = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0),
              var3 = c(0,0,0,2,2),
              var4 = c(0,0,"NA", "NA", "NA")))
```

what I want is something that looks like this:

```
df1<- (data.frame(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
              var1 = c(1,0 ,2 ,0 ,0 ),
              var2 = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0),
              var3 = c(0,0,0,2,2),
              var4 = c(0,0,"NA", "NA", "NA"),
              var5 = c( 1,2,2,2,2)))
```

the new variable var5 is the one I want to create from the values found in var1:var4
I know how to do a `ifelse` statement and try doing a loop unsuccessfully.

Comment: Do you want Max of four columns? If yes try rowwise!

Answer (score 0):

If all your columns are numeric, you can use `rowSums()`.  Like this:

```
df1<- data.frame(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                  var1 = c(1,0 ,2 ,0 ,0 ),
                  var2 = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0),
                  var3 = c(0,0,0,2,2),
                  var4 = c(0,0,NA, NA, NA))

df2$var5 <- rowSums(df1[,2:5], na.rm = TRUE)

df2
#   ID var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
# 1  a    1    0    0    0    1
# 2  b    0    2    0    0    2
# 3  c    2    0    0   NA    2
# 4  d    0    0    2   NA    2
# 5  e    0    0    2   NA    2
```